# Tricky Java problem to split and manipulate String

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I need to create a function in Java translate_string(),
which is doing "translation" of the string letter by letter.
Function takes String as arg, and returns array of String[]:

```
public static String[] translate_string(String string)
```

Given existing function translate_letter(),
which takes String as arg and returns array of String[]

```
public static String[] translate_letter(String letter)
```

and it translating each letter, I need to sequentially translate
the whole string letter by letter into combination of output strings.
Complexity is, that one character could be translated to multiple
sets of characters, it is not one-to-one relationship between 
input string and output string, it is - one-to-many relationship,
where one letter as input could produce multiple combinations
(i.e. arrays) as output.

N.B.: Term translation has nothing to do with actual translation from 
one language to another, it is just substitution of one character
to set of other characters.

Below is exact code id simplified version of function
translate_letter() (no modification is required):

```
//------------------------------------------------------------
// translate letters - return array of diff combinations
public static String[] translate_letter(String s) {

    ArrayList<String> o = new ArrayList<>(1);

    if ( s.equals("a") ) { // if a 
        o.add("a1");
    } else {

        if ( s.equals("b") ) { // if b
            o.add("b1"); o.add("b2");
        } else {

            if ( s.equals("c") ) { // if c 
                o.add("c1"); o.add("c2"); o.add("c3");
            } else {

                if ( s.equals("d") ) { // if d 
                    o.add("d1"); o.add("d2"); o.add("d3"); o.add("d4");
                } else {

                    o.add(s); // s = def add (if nothing above matches)

                } // end if d 

            } // end if c

        } // end if b

    } // end if a

    //Convert ArrayList o to string array[]
    String[] array = o.toArray(new String[o.size()]);

    return array;

} // end translate_letter()
//------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, how to translate the string?
Let's have a look at simple version of translate - when 
translate_letter() return just string.
So, letter "a" will be translated to "a1", letter "b" 
will be translated to "b1", "c" - to "c1".
Input string "a" will be translated as "a1", simple.
Input string "ab" will be translated as "a1b1", simple.
Input string "abc" will be translated as "a1b1c1", simple.
I don't need to create this simple version - it is nothing to do here,
just split the input string and translate each letter by letter.

What I want to write (and I cannot do this) - is complicated version of translate_string(),
when function translate_letter() returns multiple combinations,
i.e. - array of output combinations.

For example (according to the code of translate_letter() above,
letter "a" will be translated to "a1", simple.
But letter "b" will be translated by translate_letter() to 2 combinations: 
"b1" and "b2", 
and output is String[] array = {"b1", "b2" }

So, string "a" will be translated by translate_string() as array of 
just 1 element R[] = { "a1" }

```
String "ab" will be translated as array of 2 elements 
R[] = { "a1b1", "a1b2" }

String "abc" will be translated as: 
R[] = { "a1b1c1", "a1b1c2", "a1b1c3", "a1b2c1", "a1b2c2", "a1b2c3" }

String "db" will be translated as: 
R[] = { "d1b1", "d2b1", "d3b1", "d4b1", "d1b2", "d2b2", "d3b2", "d4b2" }
```

This task is more complicated, than it seems initially just by
look at it. I have tried and failed with 2 approaches - simple Arrays[]
and Array[] of ArrayList - cannot loop through two array (with different
indexes) at once and need some external help or ideas - how to accomplish this.

Comment: instead of IF-Else ..try using IF- ELSE IF - ELSE IF - ELSE ..code will be cleaner

Comment: Shouldn’t `db` become `{ "d1b1", "d2b1", "d3b1", "d4b1", "d1b2", "d2b2", "d3b2", "d4b2" }`?

Comment: I can't tell from your problem description whether a letter repeats because of its position in the String, or repeats because of its position in the alphabet?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the rare occasions I'll answer homework, though Ole V.V. is right.
When we do the homework, the learning effect is relative, and it is not honest with respect to those wo struggled.

```
public static String[] translate_string(String s) {
    Set<String> translations = new HashSet<>();
    if (!s.isEmpty()) {
        s.codePoints(cp -> {
            String letter = new String(new int[] {cp}, 0, 1);
            String[] more = translate_letter(letter);
            if (more.length == 0) {
            } else if (more.length == 1) {
                translations.add(more[0]);
            } else {
                Set<String> prior_translations = new HashSet<>(translations);
                translations.clear();
                for (String prior: prior_translations) {
                    for (String letter: letter_translations) {
                        translations.add(prior + letter);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return translations.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

The trick is: when having **N** translations and getting for a next letter **L** letter translations, the result is **N×L** translations.

The answer of Ole V.V. explains things better.